# Formula using sumifs and indirect function for worksheets. Getting Reference error although Had it working with different columns

Tags: excel, array-formulas

Using excel 365.  I have used this same formula for "asset allocations" and it worked perfectly.
I decided to do the same for sector allocation and I can not figure out what is wrong. This has beat me down. I have tried for 2 days.  I thought that I could just exchange the category for sector.  Didn't work. Thank you for any help.

Here is the image which shows the sheet that I am using.
The formula in G6 is:

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(K$6:K$11&"[Value]"),INDIRECT(K$6:K$11&"[Sectors]"),[@Sector]))
You can see a REF Error on the column "Value".

[image: sector allocation table]

This image is to show where the "Sectors" are listed on the individual sheets that I wish to sum.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unusual, but this is working fine in my test scenario.

Use the Evaluate Formula tool to see where the error creeps in. You may have a typo in the list of tables.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  You say unusual.  Do you have a solution that is better? I am piecing together things from other code that I have used before. I am not an expert in any way and would welcome anything better than. this. I didn't even know about Evaluate formula. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I should have found the answer earlier but I didn't question my table columns.
In my last table the Column was accidentally called "Sector" and it should have been called "Sectors". I needed to pinpoint the point of problem by debugging better.
This code does indeed work fine for anyone wishing to sum by a category from more than one sheet. Not saying it is elegant code but it is easy to understand.